# Filter Data Frame which has list as a Column Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, filter

I am trying to filter a data frame which is saved in a csv file. The data frame is as follows :
Sample Dataframe

```
A B C
x 3 ['a',1,2,'b']
y 2 ['c',4,6,'b']
z 1 ['d',5,7,'e']
```

The above data frame contains of three columns but the third column C has list a value. I know for a fact that I can use `df.query('A == x')` and it will print out the rows which contains values as 'x'. But how can I do the same for the column C. Suppose I want to print rows from column C which does not contain 'b'. Basically it should print

```
z 1 ['d',5,7,'e'].
```

Comment: Which does not contain "b" as the third item or any item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use an apply function
`df[df['C'].apply(lambda x: 'b' not in x)]`

Edit: if you want to filter any row that contains 'b' or 3, you can do:
`df[df['C'].apply(lambda x: np.all(['b' not in x, 3 not in x]))]`

Likewise, if you want to filter out rows that contain both 'b' and 3 (but either just 'b' or 3 is allowed) you can change the above to np.any instead of np.all

Comment: What about multiple values? Say If I want to add multiple values and not just b. How can I do that?

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your follow on question

Comment: It doesn't seem to work Not Sure why. Because I can still see those values are getting printed. I believe this is the solution but just need to make some slight changes not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

To filter out the rows that contain "b" as the third item:

```
out = df[df['C'].str[2].ne('b')]
```

For any item:

```
out = df[["b" not in l for l in df['C']]]
```

To remove rows matching both "a" AND "b":

```
out = df[[{'a', 'b'}.issubset(l) for l in df['C']]
```

For either "a" OR "b":

```
out = df[[not {'a', 'b'}.isdisjoint(l) for l in df['C']]
```

Comment: How do you want to match multiple values? Can you give an example? (For example it could be "a and b" or "a or b")

Comment: The column value is a list. In that list there are both string and integers. I need to filter out the whole dataframe based on string from that list which is a column value.

Comment: @ANISH ok but this doesn't explain the logic of selection. Anyway, I provided most possibilities that you could need, give them a try and let me know if this works. If not provide a better example.